# Angular2 - RC6 Updgrade and @angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/src/facade/lang 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I've just upgraded my angular2 RC5 application to RC6. I am using [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/) seed project.

After the upgrade when I run the application I get an error

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:63342/trips-portal-app/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/src/facade/lang 404 (Not Found)
```

Complete screenshot of developer tools is given below:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing bits one by one from my application, I found that this error is caused by [angular2-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie) library as it is trying to use an API which angular team has made private in RC6.

Issue is already reported [here](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/15) on GitHub and the developer is working on it.

Comment: Library is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "ng2-translate": "~2.4.3",
    ...
}
```

in package.json.

There is a fix for RC6 which wasn't downloaded automatically as I used npm install without setting version explicitly.

https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Comment: I am not using angular translate library. However, I added dependency for `ng2-translate` but it didn't work.